# Manually calculating IEEE-754 floating point fractions and splitting up the bits - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point, binary, ieee-754

I'm trying to come up with a way to do this:

Lets say the fraction portion of my IEEE-754 floating point number is `0b10110011001100110011010`

I'm trying to take each bit and multiply it by a power of 2 cooresponding to it's bit position and add them all up.

so like this: `1*2-1+ 0*2-2 + 1*2-3 + 1*2-4 + 0*2-5 + 0 * 2-6 + ...`

I can't for the life of me figure out how to split the number up into bits.

Ideally it'd be something like this:

```
In [33]: value = 0x6f

In [34]: result = function(value)

In [35]: result

Out[35]: [0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1]
```

Doesn't have to be a list but a tuple would work fine too.

Then I am pretty confident I can do a `for i in result` function to get the answer I need.  But if you've got ideas on how to do the second part I'm all ears as well!

Any ideas?

Comment: `bin(0x6f)` Is what you need

Comment: do you want to convert your hex value to a binary ?

Comment: Seems like an XY problem.  What is it you *really* want to get?  The exact value of a `float`?  Its internal representation in memory?

Comment: No need to process separate bits.  `0b10110011001100110011010 / 2**23 == 0.7000000476837158`.

Comment: Note that for a normal float there is an implied +1 to the mantissa.  so really `0b10110011001100110011010 / 2**23 + 1 = 1.7000000476837158`.

Comment: @dan04 I am trying to get the representation in memory.  In the PowerPC architecture, single precision float values are stored in 64bit registers but uses 25 fraction bits.  Not the standard 23.  The remaining 29 bits in the register are 0.  I want to be able to calculate a PowerPC single precision floating point value and see it's representation in a 64 bit register.  so it will look like this:
`  Sign bit _Exp _Fraction_zereos`
`0b0_00000000_1111111111111111111111111_00000000000000000000000000000`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the raw bits of a `float`, then you can use `struct.pack` for it.

```
>>> struct.pack('@d', 0.7)
b'ffffff\xe6?'
>>> struct.pack('>d', 0.7)
b'?\xe6ffffff'
```

The prefixes are `@` for the platform-dependent “native order, size & alignment” (the default, but `@` makes it explicit), while `>` is for “big-endian, std. size & alignment”.

The big-endian one translates to the bit sequence 0_01111111110_0110011001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110, i.e.:

- A sign bit of 0, indicating that the number is positive.
- An exponent of 1022.
- A significand of 0x6666666666666.

Recall that the value of a normalized IEEE 754 `double` is `(-1)**sign * 2 ** (exponent - 1023) * (1 + significand / 2**52)`.  Plugging in sign = 0, exponent = 1022, and significand = 0x6666666666666 gives the expected 0.7 (or to be exact, 0.6999999999999999555910790149937383830547332763671875).

If you want to use math functions instead of `struct`, then `math.frexp` is your friend.  It returns a tuple of `(significand, exponent)` such that `significand * 2**exponent` gives the original number.  However, it scales the exponent so that the significand is in the interval [0.5, 1), not [1, 2), so in my code below, I have written the exponent bias as 1022 instead of 1023.

```
def ieee_double_fields(x):
    sign = 0
    if x < 0:
        sign = 1
        x = -x
    significand, exponent = math.frexp(x)
    return (sign, exponent + 1022, int((significand * 2 - 1) * 2**52))
```

This returns a tuple of integers consisting of a 1-bit sign, 11-bit exponent, and 52-bit significand (without the implicit leading 1 bit).

Handling of denormals (including ±0.0), infinities, and NaN is left as an exercise for the reader.